# Find consecutive values in 3D array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, difference

Say I have an array the size 100x150x30, a geographical grid 100x150 with 30 values for each grid point, and want to find consecutive elements along the third dimension with a congruous length of minimum 3.

I would like to find the maximum length of consecutive elements blocks, as well as the number of occurrences.

I have tried this on a simple vector:

```
var=[20 21 50 70 90 91 92 93];
a=diff(var);

q = diff([0 a 0] == 1);
v = find(q == -1) - find(q == 1);

v = v+1;
v2 = v(v>3);
v3 = max(v2); % maximum length: 4
z = numel(v2); % number: 1
```

Now I'd like to apply this to the 3rd dimension of my array.

With `A` being my 100x150x30 array, I've come this far:

```
aa = diff(A, 1, 3);

b1 = diff((aa == 1),1,3);
b2 = zeros(100,150,1);

qq = cat(3,b2,b1,b2);
```

But I'm stuck on the next step, which would be: `find(qq == -1) - find(qq == 1);`. I can't make it work.

Is there a way to put it in a loop, or do I have to find the consecutive values another way?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = randi(25,100,150,30); %// generate random array
tmpsize = size(A); %// get its size
B = diff(A,1,3); %// difference
v3 = zeros(tmpsize([1 2])); %//initialise
z = zeros(tmpsize([1 2]));
for ii = 1:100 %// double loop over all entries
    for jj = 1:150
        q = diff([0 squeeze(B(ii,jj,:)).' 0] == 1);%'//
        v = find(q == -1) - find(q == 1);
        v=v+1;
        v2=v(v>3);
        try %// if v2 is empty, set to nan
        v3(ii,jj)=max(v2);
        catch
            v3(ii,jj)=nan;
        end
        z(ii,jj)=numel(v2);
    end
end
```

The above seems to work. It just doubly loops over both dimensions you want to get the difference over.

The part where I think you were stuck was using [`squeeze`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) to get the vector to put in your variable `q`.

The `try/catch` is there solely to prevent empty consecutive arrays in `v2` throwing an error in the assignment to `v3`, since that would remove its entry. Now it simply sets it to `nan`, though you can switch that to `0` of course.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one vectorized approach -

```
%// Parameters
[m,n,r] = size(var);
max_occ_thresh = 2        %// Threshold for consecutive occurrences

% Get indices of start and stop of consecutive number islands
df = diff(var,[],3)==1;   
A = reshape(df,[],size(df,3));
dfA = diff([zeros(size(A,1),1) A zeros(size(A,1),1)],[],2).'; %//'
[R1,C1] = find(dfA==1);
[R2,C2] = find(dfA==-1);

%// Get interval lengths
interval_lens = R2 - R1+1;

%// Get max consecutive occurrences across dim-3
max_len = zeros(m,n);
maxIDs = accumarray(C1,interval_lens,[],@max);
max_len(1:numel(maxIDs)) = maxIDs

%// Get number of consecutive occurrences that are a bove max_occ_thresh
num_occ = zeros(m,n);
counts = accumarray(C1,interval_lens>max_occ_thresh);
num_occ(1:numel(counts)) = counts
```

Sample run -

```
var(:,:,1) =
     2     3     1     4     1
     1     4     1     5     2
var(:,:,2) =
     2     2     3     1     2
     1     3     5     1     4
var(:,:,3) =
     5     2     4     1     2
     1     5     1     5     1
var(:,:,4) =
     3     5     5     1     5
     5     1     3     4     3
var(:,:,5) =
     5     5     4     4     4
     3     4     5     2     2
var(:,:,6) =
     3     4     4     5     3
     2     5     4     2     2
max_occ_thresh =
     2
max_len =
     0     0     3     2     2
     0     2     0     0     0
num_occ =
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: I was waiting on you to steal the accept away from me :P

Comment: @Adriaan OP is looking for a loopy solution it seems, so I guess you were safe anyway! ;)

Comment: No loop is safe when the `bsxfun` army comes. Let alone two loops. Your solution is, obviously, lots faster

Comment: @Adriaan Was a big bug there, fixed now! :)

Comment: Thanks to the both of you, works fine! @Divakar I just added a line `max_len(max_len<=max_occ_thresh)=NaN;` to only get the maximum length of those blocks larger than the threshold